# How to tell user about what are recently received push notifications

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, push-notification

Is it possible to tell user what were about recently received push notifications ? I mean, if user clicks cancel when push was received, there is a badge on the icon of my application, but that's all. I think this is not user friendly and such notifications have no sense. When user opens an application, he knows that there is something new in it, but don't know exactly what. Do I need to make some requests to my web server to have information about my last pushes or I'm missing something and there is another way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the implementations of push notifications I've worked with so far, you'll need to make a call to your server when the app actually starts up in order for the app to know what the new information is. I don't believe there's any way to store received push notifications unless your app is opened and handling them in the app delegate. Otherwise if push notification is closed it's discarded.

In all the apps I've worked with that utilized push notifications there was a place in the app where all the recent notifications were displayed after a call to the server was made to get the whole list.